# difference in timestamp in sqlite

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, time

I am trying to find the difference between two time stamps with milliseconds in SQLITE as below

```
select abs(CAST ( (JulianDay(t1.TIME1) - JulianDay(t1.TIME2) ) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 AS INTEGER) ) diff_millisec 
from time_table;
```

For this data:

```
t1.TIME1 - 14:14:04.446258 
t1.TIME2 - 14:14:04.446377
```

The answer is 0.

For another set of values

```
t1.TIME1 - 14:13:27.742646
t1.TIME2 - 14:13:27.649184
```

The answer is 93

Why does the first set gives 0 ? Is there a way to give precise value.

Comment: The results that you get are correct. The difference of the first 2 timestamps is 0 milliseconds and for the last 2 is 93 milliseconds. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite provides accuracy up to milliseconds when a function like `julianday()` is used, because only the first three digits (after the dot) are significant to the result, as it is mentioned in [Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), so both time strings `14:14:04.446258` and `14:14:04.446377` are evaluated as `14:14:04.446` and are considered equal.

So, the results that you get in milliseconds are correct.

If you want the difference in microseconds, you should add the difference of the last 3 digits of the 2 times:

```
select abs(CAST(
        (JulianDay(TIME1) - JulianDay(TIME2)) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000 + 
        (substr(TIME1, -3) - substr(TIME2, -3))
        AS INTEGER
        )) diff_microsec 
from time_table;
```

but for better accuracy you should use `strftime()` to get the difference in seconds and then add the difference in microseconds:

```
select abs((strftime('%s', TIME1) - strftime('%s', TIME2)) * 1000 * 1000 + 
           (substr(TIME1, -6) - substr(TIME2, -6))
       ) diff_microsec 
from time_table;
```

or:

```
select abs((strftime('%s', TIME1) - strftime('%s', TIME2)) * 1000 * 1000 + 
           (substr(TIME1, instr(TIME1, '.') + 1) - substr(TIME2, instr(TIME1, '.') + 1))
       ) diff_microsec 
from time_table;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c954c6ec4299810098568a63b89bbe72).